# Parse Django JsonResponse with Angular 4

Tags: python, json, django, angular, request

I'm using Django for send JsonResponse. If I map response.json() Angular return me an error that I can't handle. Furthermore, if I use response.text() for visualizing data it return something like that:

> Response: {u'foo': u'bar', u'title': u'hello world'}

In Angular 4 I've this code:

```
return this._http.post(this.serverUrl, JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers})
      .map((response:Response) => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

In Django Python I've this code:

```
response= {'foo': 'bar', 'title': 'hello world'}
return JsonResponse(response, safe=False);
```

I've also tryed this:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8',)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response))
return json.dumps(response)
return response
```

Comment: What's the response you actually get from the server? The one that starts with `R`.

Comment: The server return me this response (tested also with Postman):

`Response: Content-Type: application/json {"title": "hello world"}`

Comment: `return HttpResponse(
                        json.dumps(responseDictionary) ,
                        mimetype="application/json"
                        )` ? Also, have you checked if you have some funky middleware converting things?

Comment: You're right man! My mistake, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def profile(request):
    data =  {'foo': 'bar', 'title': 'hello world'}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```